# How to properly import HighCharts with Backbone-boilerplate in an ECMAScript 2015 way?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, highcharts, ecmascript-6, backbone-boilerplate

I'm using the latest [Backbone-boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate), which adopts ECMAScript 2015 as a default grammar. I'm planning on using [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) on this project but stuck with an `import` issue of Highcharts.

My implementation is as follows.

#### home.js (which is the default index `Backbone.View` of Backbone-boilerplate)

```
import Component from '../../component';
import template from './home.html';
import Pitch from '../../modules/pitches/index';
import $ from 'jquery';
import highcharts from 'highcharts-release/highcharts';

// Import components.
import '../components/sample-component';

export default Component.extend({
    template,

    initialize: function () {
        this.template.registerPartial('nav', require('../partials/nav.html'));
        this.collection = new Pitch.Collection();
        this.collection.fetch({});
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset sync', this.render);
    },

    afterRender: function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'scatter',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Title'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Subtitle'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I've tried different combinations to get it working but none of them succeeded.

- `import highcharts from 'highcharts-release/highcharts'`
- `import highcharts from 'highcharts'`
- `import 'highcharts-release/highcharts'`
- `import 'highcharts'`

I get this error, which seems that Highcharts doesn't get imported at all.

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).highcharts is not a function

What is the proper way to import HighCharts in an ECMAScript 2015 Way?

Comment: When you open the page, in the console write: `Highcharts.version` - it should be 4.1.10. If you will get the error, then indeed Highcharts are not included. Have you added in the `package.json` Highcharts dependancy? Try out both, 4.1.9 and 4.1.10 versions - those are quite different when comes to NPM package.

Comment: @PawełFus Thank you for your suggestion. Finally I came to render graphs (I posted the answer.) but there's another problem. Please take a look and let me know if I should post another question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem occurred with jQuery. Following the instruction to [use Highcharts with jQuery](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm) "kinda" solved the initial problem.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
require('highcharts')($);
```

Graphs are rendered well except that there's a `highcharts.js:315 Uncaught TypeError: c is not a function | highcharts.js:315` error on console. For further information, I'm currently using Highcharts 4.1.10.

UPDATE: After [Highcharts 4.2.0](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/releases/tag/v4.2.0), the following is valid.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';

...

let chart = new Highcharts.Chart();
```

Comment: Could you include highcharts.src.js file? I mean `require('highcharts/lib/highcharts.src.js')($)` Sounds exactly like this [issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4818) (each is not a function)

Comment: @PawełFus When I include `highcharts.src.js`, I get `Uncaught TypeError: each is not a function | highcharts.src.js:18070`. So, yeah I think I'm having the same issue.